# Растянуть фон до конца страницы

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

У меня есть фон всего сайта в виде картинки, с ним всё хорошо. А также у меня есть для центральной части значение CSS : `background-color: white`. Как мне сделать чтобы этот белый цвет был растянут до низа страницы?

В общем хочу сделать как [тут](http://ks-shoes.by/catalog/).

Comment: Таки что конкретно непонятно, как растянуть блок с белым цветом? Код попыток есть?

Comment: Да, блок с белым цветом. А разве это не в css делается?

Comment: пример html-разметки добавьте, где не получается растянуть блок.

Comment: на каждой странице для блока div-content мне нужно растянуть

Comment: div-content - на сколько я понял блок по середине сайта, задайте ему background: #fff; и все.... он будет тянутся в зависимости от контента в нем.... если хотите чтобы он был на всю страницу напишите ему высоту 100%, ваш вопрос не понятен, поэтому просим код в студию...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дайте вашему блоку с фоном белого цвета минимальную высоту окна браузера:
min-height: 100vh;